# Counting windows

Tags: x11, window-management

Is there a command to get the number of (visible or iconified) X11 windows? The command

```
$ xwininfo -children -root
```

returns a long list of windows but most of them are neither visible nor iconified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a better estimate with:

```
wmctrl -l | wc -l
```

(which gives 40 windows, compared to 312 for `xwininfo`)

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Anthon.